# SQL Server query combination

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a query that I have to run that requires me to get rows from a table based on the value of a field in another table (which I have gotten earlier).

I currently have it done like this (simplified).

```
cmd.commandtext = "SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE FieldC = '" & TableA.FieldF & "'"
cmdReader = cmd.executereader()
If cmdReader.HasRows Then
    Do something
Else
    cmdReader.close()
    cmd.commandtext = "SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE FieldC = 'Generic'"
    cmdReader = cmd.executereader()
    If cmdReader.HasRows Then
        Do something
    Else
        Do something
    End If
End If
```

Is there a way that I can combine those two queries so that I get one or the other?

Let me know if you need any more info, not sure I've explained this properly.

Comment: You need to read up on [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: do you only want to return "generic" FieldC values where there are no values that match FieldF?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm looking for. What I have above does it but I was just wondering if it was possible to do it in the SQL rather than in VB.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
WHERE FieldC = '" & TableA.FieldF & "' OR FieldC = 'Generic'
```

Or

```
WHERE FieldC IN ('" & TableA.FieldF & "', 'Generic')
```

Even better, use parameters:

```
WHERE FieldC IN (@FieldF, 'Generic')
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldF", TableA.FieldF);
```

EDIT: To select only one set of rows in one query, you could:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    TableB 
WHERE   FieldC = @FieldF
UNION ALL
SELECT  * 
FROM    TableB 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE FieldC = @FieldF)
        AND FieldC = 'Generic'
```

Comment: Will this not return all rows for both the `TableA.FieldF` and `Generic` values? I want to return one or the other.

Comment: @Nalum: Ok, that's kind of not easy in SQL.  One way is a `union`, added to the answer

Comment: Would you recommend against doing this? Is it better done in the VB.NET code or in the SQL or is there not enough of a difference to matter?

Comment: @Nalum: Both have their place.  I'd go for the one that you find easiest to read.  For me that would be the SQL solution, but I'm a SQL guy ;) hehe